# Ionic build iOS error in ng-cordova iBeacon plugin

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I got the following error when trying to build for iOS:

> com.unarin.cordova.beacon/CDVLocationManager.m:49:30: error: property
>   'allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates' not found on object of type
>   'CLLocationManager *'
>           self.locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = YES;

when i try to build for iOs this com.unarin.cordova.beacon plugin pops this error and build fails.

Comment: can you please remove and add plugin again? and try to build

Comment: @Naitik yes i did.but no use.

Comment: it may be issue only with plugin specific code or you can try to remove and add platform it's not a solution but it solved most probably. :)

Comment: go to through: https://github.com/petermetz/cordova-plugin-ibeacon